# datalist and sassLint error: vendor prefixes should not be used

Tags: html, css, html-datalist

I am using the HTML5 datalist tag, and I want to remove the default arrow for it:
[image-of-datalist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WGOmC.png)

As far as I know this is the only way I have found to remove it:

```
&::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
  display: none;
}
```

However I am now receiving the following sassLint warning which I'm not sure how to take care, any assistance would be greatly appreciated:

```
47:6  warning  Vendor prefixes should not be used  no-vendor-prefixes
```

Answer (score 0):

so i found that since i really needed this vendor prefix, i just forced sass lint to ignore it using the following comment.

```
  // sass-lint:disable no-vendor-prefixes
  &::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
    display: none;
  }
```